# This code is about Selection sorting but when i run the code it is not working as expected

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

The program only works when the no. of elements is 2 if it is more than 2 it doesn't work.

```
#Selection Sort
L = []
n = int(input('Enter the number of elements\t:'))
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input('Enter item\t:'))
    L.append(item)
    print('List\t:')
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range ((i+1),n-1):
            if (L[j]<L[i]):
                (L[j],L[i]) = (L[i],L[j])
print(L)
```

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEtDK.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQeNi.png)

Comment: you are using `i` several times. ferst time in `for i in range(n):` and second `for i in range(n-1):`

Comment: oh so what should i do btw i am a new programmer and this code was written in my book.

Comment: I think it's actually just the indentation of for i in range(n-1)... it should have no indentation so that it is run after you have entered all of the items.

The reason for your error is that you are trying to access L items before you've entered them into the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L = []
n = int(input('Enter the number of elements\t:'))
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input('Enter item\t:'))
    L.append(item)
    print('List\t:')
#First loop from 0 to n-1
for i in range(n-1):
    #second loop from 1 to n
    for j in range ((i+1),n):
        if (L[j]<L[i]):
            (L[j],L[i]) = (L[i],L[j])

print(L)
```

input

```
Enter item      :5
List    :
Enter item      :2
List    :
Enter item      :3
List    :
Enter item      :1
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: one loop was superfluous, updated the code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
enter code here
#Declare variable for selection sort
L = []
n = int(input('Enter the number of elements\t:'))
#iterate for add values
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input('Enter item\t:'))
    L.append(item)
    print('List\t:')
#iterate for select minimun value and swap value in the array    
for i in range(len(L)):
    # Find the minimum element in remaining 
    # unsorted array
    min_idx = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
        if L[min_idx] > L[j]:
            min_idx = j
              
    # Swap the found minimum element with 
    # the first element        
    L[i], L[min_idx] = L[min_idx], L[i]
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#Selection Sort
L = []
n = int(input('Enter the number of elements\t:'))
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input('Enter item\t:'))
    L.append(item)
print('List\t:')
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range ((i+1),n):
        if (L[j]<L[i]):
            (L[j],L[i]) = (L[i],L[j])
print(L)
```

Output:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb829.png)

Comment: Hi, this section is for answers only. Please add additional information directly to your post and delete this answer.